# Equivalent of onLoad in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function when I am doing a request for an image in javascript

```
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
};
```

this works as intended, but when I try and do something like this in jQuery

```
success: function (data) {
 console.log("hi");
 }
```

nothing gets printed. I inspect the request using the developer chrome window and the request works fine but for some reason is not calling the function within the success clause. Is there any way that I can make that function be called regardless of how the request executes? Like onLoad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [complete](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), as it executes regardless of the response status:

```
complete: function (data) {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

> complete
>
> [...]
>
> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Comment: Thank you sir! will accept as soon as it lets me :)

Answer (score -3):

Another alternative -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Write code here 

});
```